# How to pass a string as a parameter MySQL to a stored procedure used in an IN clause?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a procedure that I pass parameters to:

```sql
CALL GetSelectedCodesCount('46.12', 'yes', 'uo');
```

And it works, but I need to pass several different numeric values in the first parameter.
Like this:

```sql
CALL GetSelectedCodesCount(" '46.12' , '46.13' ", 'yes', 'uo');
```

Since these parameters then fall into the IN sample and I would like to pass exactly such a tape.
I've tried various combinations including sending a parameter. If I send only one numeric value everything works, but if more than one I get 0.

I also tried to work on the selectedCodes string.

```sql
SET selectedCodes = REPLACE(selectedCodes, ' ', '');
SET selectedCodes = CONCAT("'", REPLACE(selectedCodes, ",", "','"), "'");
SET selectedCodes = REPLACE(selectedCodes, '"', "' ");
```

And it seems to get a value that is correctly formatted for the IN statement, but I still get null :(

My procedure:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`***`@`%` PROCEDURE `database`.`GetSelectedCodesCount`(
    IN selectedCodes TEXT, 
    IN primaryCondition VARCHAR(50),
    IN tableName VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE result INT;
    DECLARE result_uo INT;
    DECLARE result_fop INT;

    IF tableName = 'uo' THEN
        -- Performing selection for UO
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_uo
        FROM table1 
        JOIN table2 ON table2.CODE = table1.CODE 
        JOIN table3 ON table3.RECORD = table2.RECORD 
        WHERE table1.CODE IN (selectedCodes) 
        AND table3.STAN = 'registered' 
        AND (primaryCondition IS NULL OR table2.PRIMARY = primaryCondition);

        SET result = result_uo;
    ELSEIF tableName = 'fop' THEN
        -- Performing selection for FOP
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_fop
        FROM table1 
        JOIN table4 ON table4.CODE = table1.CODE 
        JOIN table5 ON table5.RECORD = table4.RECORD 
        WHERE table1.CODE IN (selectedCodes) 
        AND table5.STAN = 'registered' 
        AND (primaryCondition IS NULL OR table4.PRIMARY = primaryCondition);

        SET result = result_fop;
    ELSE
        -- Performing selection for both types 
        -- Selection for UO
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_uo
        FROM table1 
        JOIN table2 ON table2.CODE = table1.CODE 
        JOIN table3 ON table3.RECORD = table2.RECORD 
        WHERE table1.CODE IN (selectedCodes) 
        AND table3.STAN = 'registered' 
        AND (primaryCondition IS NULL OR table2.PRIMARY = primaryCondition);

        -- Selection for FOP
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO result_fop
        FROM table1 
        JOIN table4 ON table4.CODE = table1.CODE 
        JOIN table5 ON table5.RECORD = table4.RECORD 
        WHERE table1.CODE IN (selectedCodes) 
        AND table5.STAN = 'registered' 
        AND (primaryCondition IS NULL OR table4.PRIMARY = primaryCondition);

        -- Returning the sum of results
        SET result = result_uo + result_fop;
    END IF;

    SELECT result;
END
```

Comment: Provide needed parameters list as solid CSV string. Use `WHERE FIND_IN_SET()` instead of `WHERE IN ()`.

Comment: The linked question is about MySQL, but in this case the solution is the same for MariaDB.

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` _may_ be slower.  But it provide some protection against "SQL Injection".

Answer (score 0):

A sample:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
SELECT 1 id, 123.456 val UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 234.567 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 345.678;

CREATE PROCEDURE test (IN criteria TEXT)
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(test.val, criteria);

CALL test('123.456,234.432,345.678');
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123.456 |
| 3 | 345.678 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yEpYfSJj)

---

> It works, but it increased the sampling time significantly. – WarmingZ

If so then provide your values list as CSV/JSON, parse in the query to the rowset (JSON_TABLE) then join to data source table.

```
CREATE TABLE test 
SELECT 1 id, 123.456 val UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 234.567 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 345.678;

CREATE PROCEDURE test (IN criteria TEXT)
SELECT test.*
FROM test
JOIN JSON_TABLE( CONCAT('[', criteria, ']'),
                 '$[*]' COLUMNS (val DECIMAL(10,3) PATH '$')
                 ) jsontable USING (val);

CALL test('123.456,234.432,345.678');
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123.456 |
| 3 | 345.678 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fKkUBFPD)

Comment: It works, but it increased the sampling time significantly.

Comment: @WarmingZ You will get better performace if you put the values from the parameter string into a temporary table using `JSON_TABLE` sample @Akina showed, and then use the temporary table in the query.

Comment: @WarmingZ - If speed is a big concern, note that most of the suggestions here and in the linked queries are _not_ fast.  Consider starting a new Question with an emphasis on speed.  That may open the Answers up to even more solutions, such as a temp table or parsing the commalist, etc.